# Local filesystem mounted as remote by systemd in OL8.6

Tags: linux, systemd, mount, oracle-linux, systemd-mount

Two RAID SSDs partitioned as follows.

```
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 65536 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BF152674-71D5-491B-8C35-09F3AA0015EE

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   2099199   2097152    1G EFI System
/dev/sda2    2099200   4196351   2097152    1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3    4196352 759171071 754974720  360G Linux LVM
/dev/sda4  759171072 885000191 125829120   60G Linux LVM
/dev/sda5  885000192 918554623  33554432   16G Linux swap


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_root-root: 48 GiB, 51535413248 bytes, 100655104 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 65536 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_u-u: 288 GiB, 309233451008 bytes, 603971584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 65536 bytes
```

The /u partition is mounted as remote-fs by systemd.

```
# ll /run/systemd/generator/remote-fs.target.requires/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 26 21:32 u.mount -> ../u.mount
```

This causes issues when services start after reboot, as /u is not mounted until network services have started.

Have engineer a workaroun by inserting the following for effected services.

```
RequiresMountsFor=/u
```

Looking for a better solution of /u being mounted as local-fs (as it should be) to avoid future issues.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided nothing on `/u` vitally depends on `/`, you can force `/u` to mount before other local filesystems. One method would be to add the `x-systemd.before=local-fs.target` option in `fstab`. E.g.:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_u-u  /u  xfs  defaults,x-systemd.before=local-fs.target  0 0
```

Then force systemd to regenerate its unit files:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```